# Would asking about ways to avoid mentioning a function pointer's arguments inside the definition of a function that takes it as argument be on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I'm writing this C code that involves passing around a lot of function pointers, and sometimes writing all the arguments that a function pointer takes when defining a function that takes it as a variable can significantly increase the length of the function definition and thus decrease its readability. For instance, say I have this function `foo` that takes three `int`s and a function pointer to perform a certain operation. The typical way to declare a function like `foo` is something along the lines of:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int (*operation) (int, int, int));
```

I was wondering if it would be on topic for SO to ask if there was a possible way to avoid the redundancy of having to re-mention the variable types  another time in the type of the function pointer.

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75305328/in-c-can-you-omit-the-parameter-types-of-a-function-pointer-when-initializing-i) suggests that it is possible to only use empty parentheses `()` , which translates in the above example to:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int (*operation) ());
```

However, a comment to the same post states that this kind of syntax is going to be removed in C23:

> As a side note, this is obsolescent C since year 1989. Empty
> parenthesis () no prototype style should not be used. And it will
> finally get removed in upcoming C23

Comment: Is there any particular reason you think this would be off-topic? It's a narrow programming question with an objective answer.

Comment: @vandench-onstrike I was wondering if it doesn't tilt toward a question about programming style or design or doing something that shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we boil down your question, you ask:

> How can I avoid this redundancy?

Analyzing this question (-type) by the [dont-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) gives us:

- *Is such question [about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?* → Yes, you want to know how to code something. It is not off-topic.
- *Is it a subjective question*?* → No, you want to make your code more efficient. Efficiency is objective, you can measure it. Your question should clarify by what metric (time, resource consumption, code/file size, read- & maintainability, etc) you want to make your code more efficient.

Your question is good to go, as long as you provide enough detail.

---

* Some subjective questions are allowed, as per the [dont-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

Comment: It’s not about efficiency of compiled code though, it’s about readability and avoiding redundancy. It’s still on topic, but not for the reasons mentioned in this answer.

Comment: "*Efficiency is objective, you can measure it (time, resource consumption, code/file size, etc).*" Questions about efficiency require OP to clarify the metrics they care about and what acceptable values of said metrics will be. Questions asking only "how can I make this code more efficient" are close-worthy as needing details.

Comment: @CrisLuengo readability means having to spend less time on (trying to understand) a project, making you more efficient.